# django - Natural key serialization of User

Tags: python, django, json, serialization

Suppose I have a model of a comment in my project:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

When serialized to JSON using `django.core.serializers` the author field comes out as:

```
"author": 1 // use_natural_keys = False
"author": ["someuser"] // use_natural_keys = True
```

Suppose I want to output the user's first and last name as well? How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're serializing your model in order to transmit it on wire (like in a http response).

`django.core.serializers` is likely not the way you want to go. A quick approach would be to include a method on the model to return the dictionary you want to be serialized, then use `simplejson.dumps` to serialize it. E.g.:

```
def to_json(self):
    return dict(
        author=[self.author.natural_key(), self.author.first_name, self.author.last_name],
        text=self.text,
    )
```

then just call `simplejson.dumps(comment.to_json())`.